# Open retail/ecommerce dataset with customers, transactions, products, loyalty, discounts, promotion information?

Tags: dataset, data

Does anyone know of an open retail/e-commerce dataset with information about customers, transactions, products, loyalty, discounts, and promotion information?

I am planning to create 360-degree customer view. This includes customer segmentation, churn analysis, market basket analysis, Customer Lifetime Value, Future Value predictions, etc.

I have tried Kaggle, UCLA ML repo and the internet but haven't found data with complete information.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following websites as well, as they have huge data:
https://data.gov, https://www.re3data.org/repository/r3d100011043 and https://academictorrents.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:
[Kaggle - Brazillian e-Commerce dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce) . It has customer data. With feature engineering effort, you can produce a 360 dataset. Infact, I think there is a kernel on it.